# Does pointer arithmetic apply to iterators?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, iterator

Suppose you have the following vector and C array:

```
vector<long> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
for (auto start_itr = v.begin(); start_itr != v.end(); ++start_itr) {
    statements;
}
```

and

```
long ary[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
for (long *ptr = ary; ptr < (ary+5); ++ptr) {
    statements;
}
```

In the code for the array, the ++ptr refers to adding 1 to ptr, i.e. pointer arithmetic - adding 8 bytes move to the next long element of the array. For the vector, however, does the same principle of pointer arithmetic apply; i.e. adding 1 to start_itr means moving up 8 bytes to the next element b/c it is a vector of longs?

I know the iterator type is essentially a pointer, and this would make sense, but I want to be sure.

Comment: i think the compiler can confirm your hypothesis.

Comment: `I know the iterator type is essentially a pointer` First it is only true for certain kind of iterator, like iterator of vector.  Your statement seems over-generalized.  Second, I doubt if the language standard itself has guaranteed `vector::iterator` should always be pointer.  Personally I would just avoid treating iterator to be equivalent to pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators on vectors are a cost-free abstraction of pointers.  So `++` moves forward one, `+7` moves 7, etc.

Vector iterators are random access iterators, so they behave a lot like pointers.  Just like pointers, advancing past one-past-the-last element (aka `.end()`) is undefined behaviour.

Other iterators are more constrained; `std::list` or `std::map` doea not support `+7`, but does support `++`.